# Every square matrix is the sum of two invertible matrices, over any field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Any hint would be appreciated.

Is this also true for finite fields?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202533/show-any-matrix-a-n-times-n-can-be-written-as-sum-of-two-nonsingular-matrice

Comment: The same proof works for $n\times n$ matrices with $n\le |F|-2$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $F$ is a field with at least $3$ distinct elements $0,1,\alpha$. Let $A\in$Mat$_n(F)$ and $d_i=a_{ii}$ be its diagonal elements. If $d_i\neq1$, put $e_i:=1$; if $d_i=1$, put $e_i:=\alpha$. Then $$A=L+U,$$
where $L$ is lower triangular with diagonal $e_i$ and $U$ is upper triangular with diagonal $d_i-e_i$. By construction, the diagonal entries of both $L$ and $U$ are all nonzero; since the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal entries, both $L$ and $U$ are nonsingular.

**UPDATE:**

When $F:=\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field with $2$ elements, we can get every matrix in Mat$_n(F)$ as a sum of at most $n+2$ nonsingular matrices (I don't know if this number is sharp; this is just what I came up with). Here is how:

Denote by $G_i$ the matrix full of ones except for the diagonal, which is $0$ except for the $i$th entry, which is $1$ (i.e., $G_i=1-I+E_i$, where $1$ is the full-of-ones matrix, $I$ is the identity and $E_i$ is the diagonal $i$th elementary matrix). Observe that $G_i$ has a row $R$ full of ones, while the other rows have just one $0$, each in a different position. Since the characteristic is $2$, by sequentially adding $R$ to the other rows and after that sequentially adding the other rows to $R$, we get $\det(G_i)=\det(I)=1$. Therefore the matrices $G_i$ are nonsingular.

Now write
$$A=L+U+\sum_{i=1}^n d_iG_i,$$
where $L$ is lower triangular with diagonal full of ones and $U$ is upper triangular with diagonal full of ones.